# Spring Boot app with Hibernate multi-tenant support

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I have started converting an existing Spring Boot(1.5.4.RELEASE) application to support multi-tenant capabilities. So i am using MySQL as the database and Spring Data JPA as the data access mechanism. i am using the schema based multi-tenant approach. As Hibernate document suggests below

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

I have implemented `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` and `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`  interfaces and I am using `ThreadLocal` variable to maintain the current tenant for the incoming request.

```
public class TenantContext {

final public static String DEFAULT_TENANT = "master";

private static ThreadLocal<Tenant> tenantConfig = new ThreadLocal<Tenant>() {
    @Override
    protected Tenant initialValue() {
        Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
        tenant.setSchemaName(DEFAULT_TENANT);
        return tenant;
    }
};

public static Tenant getTenant() {
    return tenantConfig.get();
}

public static void setTenant(Tenant tenant) {
    tenantConfig.set(tenant);
}

public static String getTenantSchema() {
    return tenantConfig.get().getSchemaName();
}

public static void clear() {
    tenantConfig.remove();
  }
```

}

Then i have implemented a filter and there i set the tenant dynamically looking at a request header as below

```
String targetTenantName = request.getHeader(TENANT_HTTP_HEADER);
Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
tenant.setSchemaName(targetTenantName);
TenantContext.setTenant(tenant);
```

This works fine and now my application points to different schema based on the request header value.

However there is a master schema where i store the some global settings and i need to access that schema while in a middle of a request for a tenant. Therefore i tried to hard code the Threadlocal variable just before that database call in the code as below.

```
Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
tenant.setSchemaName("master");
TenantContext.setTenant(tenant);
```

However this does not point to the master schema and instead it tries to access the original schema set during the filter. What is the reason for this?
As per my understanding Hibernate invokes openSession() during the first database call to a tenant and after i try to invoke another database call for "master" it still use the previous tenant as CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver invokes only during the openSession(). However these different database calls does not invoke within a transaction.
Can you please help me to understand the issue with my approach and any suggestions to fix the issue

Thanks
Keth

@JonathanJohx actually i am trying to override the TenantContext set by the filter in one of the controllers. First i am loging in a tenant where TenantContext is set to that particular tenant. While the request is in that tenant i am requesting data from master. In order to do that i am simply hard code the tenant as below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jobTemplates")
public class JobTemplateController {

@Autowired
JobTemplateService jobTemplateService;

@GetMapping
public JobTemplateList list(Pageable pageable){

    Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
        tenant.setSchemaName(multitenantMasterDb);

        TenantContext.setTenant(tenant);

    return jobTemplateService.list(pageable);
}
```

Comment: Can you add code where you are calling TenantContext to master?

Comment: @JonathanJohx i have appended the code to the issue description

Comment: I'm a little confused @keth, you mean a user request enters a filter where in this filter it's set the tenant, so second place controller then it in this controller you want to change the tenant to master, right? What is the flow that you want?

Comment: @JonathanJohx sorry for making you confused. Yes you are correct first user request enters a filter where in this filter it's set the tenant. This filter is responsible for authorize the user against the tenant. So once the user authorized it enters to the above mentioned JobTemplateController to fetch some common data set from the master

Comment: Okay then you might set after the filter was authorized to master...  Something like this try { authorization stuff return user..} finally { TenantContext.set("master"); } I suggest you use String instead of Tenant object JIC. @keth